# Combining Queries SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to combine two queries, just slap it on top of this result. I am not sure if that is possible. I currently have it working through a report however the report is no where near optimized.

Query #1:

```
;with cte as 
(
    SELECT
        tt.StepNo,
        o.PartNo,
        tt.WorkCntr,
        o.WorkCntr as owork,
        matl.WhereUsed as WhereUsed,
        tt.JobNo,
        tt.TicketDate,
        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.ActualPayRate as ttLaborCost,
        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.BurdenRate as mimicBurdenCost,
        tt.SetupTime as ttSetupTime,
        tt.CycleTime as ttCycleTime,
        tt.PiecesFinished,
        tt.PiecesScrapped,
        tt.ActualPayRate,
        tt.BurdenRate,
        o.SetupTime,
        o.TimeUnit,
        o.CycleTime,
        o.CycleUnit,
        o.MachRun as RoutMachRun,
        tt.MachRun,
        o.UnattendOp,
        od.DueDate,
        od.QtyToMake,
        (od.QtyToMake - od.QtyShipped2Stock) as NumOpen,
        CASE
        WHEN o.MachRun <> tt.MachRun Then 'Incorrect Ratio'
        ELSE ''
        END as IncorrectRatio,
        ROUND(cast (o.PctEff as FLOAT),2) as pctEff,
        ROUND(cast (o.ScrapPct as FLOAT),2) as scrapEff,
        (ROUND(cast((od.QtyToMake - od.QtyShipped2Stock) as FLOAT)/od.QtyToMake,3)) as Prorate,
        POTotalCost.POTotalCost,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tt.Stepno, tt.JobNo ORDER BY tt.StepNo, tt.TicketDate) as RowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tt.JobNo ORDER BY tt.JobNo) as RowNum2


    FROM
        TimeTicketDet as tt

    LEFT JOIN
        OrderRouting as o
        on tt.JobNo = o.JobNo and tt.StepNo = o.Stepno
    LEFT JOIN
        OrderDet as od
        on tt.JobNo = od.JobNo and o.PartNo = od.PartNo

    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                matl1.SubPartNo,
                STUFF((
                        SELECT ', ' + matl2.PartNo
                        FROM Materials as matl2
                        WHERE matl2.SubPartNo = matl1.SubPartNo
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ),1,1,'') as WhereUsed
            FROM
                Materials as matl1
        ) matl
        ON matl.SubPartNo = o.PartNo

--DELETED LEFT JOIN--



    WHERE
        od.Status = 'Open'

)

SELECT *

***WHERE CLAUSE DELETED FOR EASE OF READING***


FROM cte
```

Query #2: the query I would like to "slap on top" of query 1 is:

```
SELECT
    JobNo,
    CASE
        WHEN StockUnit = 'LOT' 
           THEN SUM(StockingCost * 1) 
           ELSE SUM(StockingCost * QtyPosted1)
    END as TotalCost
FROM 
    JobMaterials
GROUP BY 
    JobNo, StockUnit
```

Results from queries separately:

```
+----------------------+
| Results from query 2 |
+----------------------+
|                12345 |
|                12345 |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
| Results from query 1 |
+----------------------+
|                67890 |
|                67890 |
|                67890 |
+----------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------------------+
| Combined Results |
+------------------+
|            12345 |
|            12345 |
|            67890 |
|            67890 |
|            67890 |
+------------------+
```

Results when I try using a left join in query 1:

```
+------------------+
| Combined Results |
+------------------+
|            12345 |
|            12345 |
|            67890 |
|            12345 |
|            12345 |
|            67890 |
|            12345 |
|            12345 |
|            67890 |
+------------------+
```

I know the data is super vague, it is really hard to explain without using real data, and the outputs would eat up every bit of the 33k character limit for one `JobNo`. I have looked through many combining posts, either they don't work for me or I did not execute them correctly (it's probably the latter). I am still a super novice at SQL, so, be nice.

Answer (score 2):

If the result columns are the same data type and name you can do the following

```
 <query 1>

 UNION ALL

 <query 2>
```

That will "slap them together".

Note you are not guaranteed an order so you might want to do something like this

```
 SELECT A, B, C
 FROM (

     SELECT A, B, C, 1 AS Ord
     FROM -- rest of query

     UNION ALL

     SELECT A, B, C, 2 AS Ord
     FROM -- rest of query

 ) AS sub
 ORDER BY Ord ASC
```

Comment: It seems like I can't use a UNION ALL because I need to have query 2 in query 1 so the columns match, but doing so results duplicate rows, which is what I am trying to eliminate.

Comment: What you are saying is wrong -- do it just like I showed above.  Or create a gist of the source and share the link and I can show you how it is wrong.

Comment: I just want it to take the result from query 2 and basically cut and paste it on top of query 1. Your tip on UNION worked like a charm, so no need to sift through that code if its supposed to duplicate values

Comment: ok... but union won't work if you want to place on top -- you need union all or it will "merge" the results not place on top

Comment: You are already using a CTE everyone of these sub queries should be a CTE and then the code gets a cleaner.  I'll edit a fork -- give me a min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157308/discussion-between-rbc-kyle-bullard-and-hogan).

Comment: Welp, I can't use chat because work firewall says no

Comment: no chat for me too... https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/3ee2790f1f99ec64841e6723593e4971

Comment: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: It's all good Hogan, I am not sure the way I structured the main query that this can be done. It is working on many-to-many and I want the second query to be many-to-one. I fixed that error I just posted but now my results have quadrupled

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a UNION.

```
SELECT column FROM Table WHERE key = 1
UNION 
SELECT column FROM Table WHERE key = 2
```

would give you a result showing results from the table for both keys 1 and 2.

You can also look up the additional terms INTERSECT and EXCEPT (or MINUS).  INTERSECT will give you all the rows from the two queries which match.  EXCEPT will give you all results from the first query which don't exist in the second query.

So if our two result sets were A{1,2,3,4,5} and B{1,3,5,7,9}.

A UNION B = {1,2,3,4,5,7,9}

A INTERSECT B = {1,3,5}

A EXCEPT B (or A MINUS B) = {2,4}

Other things to keep in mind, UNION and INTERSECT are commutative.  So (A UNION B) = (B UNION A) and (A INTERSECT B = B INTERSECT A).  This is not the case with EXCEPT.  Using the above example again:

A EXCEPT B (or A MINUS B) = {2,4}

B EXCEPT A (or B MINUS A) = {7,9}

Comment: OP wants `UNION ALL`, the expected result includes duplicate rows.